# Argument type '[String?]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, swift

Code:

```
var contactArray = [nameField.text, addressField.text, phoneField.text]
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(contactArray, toFile: dataFilePath!)
//Error on contactArray: Argument type '[String?]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'
```

Since the `contactArray` is a non optional value, I can't force unwrap it, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that `contactArray` is not an optional; it's an *array of optionals.* You need to unwrap each individual element of the array as you construct it, e.g.:

```
var contactArray = [nameField.text!, addressField.text!, phoneField.text!]
```

Also, unless you plan on modifying that array later, you should use `let` instead of `var` to make sure it can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

`AnyObject` can only be used for classes
Therefore :

```
var contactArray : NSArray = [nameField.text, addressField.text, phoneField.text];
```

just make your array type `NSArray`